# Simple Python method to use text from xml element

Tags: python, xml, sockets, parsing

My extremely novice python/xml/coding aptitude has had me trying all day to unsuccessfully do something that I think should be pretty simple.

I've managed to send an XML request an a server, and the server generates a response that my script seems to be receiving, but I'd like to take the text response from the SessionID element that was returned and stick it into a variable that I can use later on.

It seems though that no matter what I try, I can't seem to get at that text.

I've been trying as best I can to wrap my head around the docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html, but I'm not having much luck.

I'm sure it's something dumb, but I've hit a wall and I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance on a simple method to get to where I'm trying to go.

$ cat script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

auth_request = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OSS xmlns="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zhone.com/OSSXML ossxml.xsd">
        <Request>
                <RequestType>authenticate</RequestType>
        </Request>
        <RequestElement>
                <Attribute>
                        <Name>loginName</Name>
                        <Value>boss</Value>
                </Attribute>
                <Attribute>
                        <Name>password</Name>
                        <Value>snaky79!OCAS</Value>
                </Attribute>
        </RequestElement>
</OSS>
'''
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("10.0.0.1", 15002))
s.send(auth_request)
buff = s.recv(400)
auth_response = ET.fromstring(buff)

print "Attempt 1:"
print auth_response.findall("*/SessionID")

print "Attempt 2:"
for a in auth_response.findall("*/status"):
        for b in a:
                print b
#print "Attempt 3:"
#c = auth_response.findall("*/status")
#for a in c:
#       print a.name
print "Attempt 4:"
print auth_response.getiterator()

print "Socket buffer:"
print buff
```

$./script.py

```
Attempt 1:
[<Element 'SessionID' at 0x1012a4d50>]
Attempt 2:
Attempt 4:
[<Element 'Response' at 0x1012a4950>, <Element 'OverAllStatus' at 0x1012a4990>, <Element 'OverAllDescription' at 0x1012a49d0>, <Element 'ResponseElement' at 0x1012a4a90>, <Element 'status' at 0x1012a4b50>, <Element 'Description' at 0x1012a4cd0>, <Element 'SessionID' at 0x1012a4d50>, <Element 'operName' at 0x1012a4d90>, <Element 'groupId' at 0x1012a4dd0>]
Socket buffer:
<Response>
<OverAllStatus>Success</OverAllStatus>
<OverAllDescription>The operation completed successfully</OverAllDescription>
<ResponseElement>
<status>Success</status>
<Description>Successfully Authenticated</Description>
<SessionID>0.379081153249641</SessionID>
<operName>boss</operName>
<groupId>99999</groupId>
</ResponseElement>
</Response>
```

FWIW, this is factory Python 2.7.10 on MacOS High Sierra.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For parsing xml, you can use `xmltodict` which will convert the xml response you are getting into dictionary, then you can easily retrieve the values of any key i.e. `SessionId` in your case.

```
import xmltodict 

response = xmltodict.parse(buff)

print response["Response"]["ResponseElement"]["SessionID"]
```

This will give you

`0.379081153249641`

Comment: Thank you!  This certainly seems simple enough.  I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in the pattern `*/SessionID` the `*` component goes down only one level.  If you properly format the XML to show the structure

```
<Response>
    <OverAllStatus>Success</OverAllStatus>
    <OverAllDescription>The operation completed successfully</OverAllDescription>
    <ResponseElement>
        <status>Success</status>
        <Description>Successfully Authenticated</Description>
        <SessionID>0.379081153249641</SessionID>
        <operName>boss</operName>
        <groupId>99999</groupId>
    </ResponseElement>
</Response>
```

you'll notice that both `status` and `SessionID` are nested two levels deep, so neither pattern works.  The simplest solution is to use XPath syntax

```
findall("//SessionID")
```

This will find all `SessionID` elements regardless of how deeply nested they are.

Comment: Thank you!  This is great info!